# how to get input file name as column within hive query

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have a hive external tables that mapped to some directory.
This directory includes a several files.

I want to run query like find file name where there is a user "abc"

```
 select file_name , usr from usrs_tables where usr = "abc"
```

But of course the data doesn't includes file name inside.

In MapReduce I can do it by

```
FileSplit fileSplit = (FileSplit)context.getInputSplit();
String filename = fileSplit.getPath().getName();
System.out.println("File name "+filename);
System.out.println("Directory and File name"+fileSplit.getPath().toString());
```

How can I do it in Hive?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Yes, you can retrieve the file the record was found in using the virtual column named `INPUT__FILE__NAME`, for example:

```
select INPUT__FILE__NAME, id, name from users where ...;
```

yields something like:

```
hdfs://localhost.localdomain:8020/user/hive/warehouse/users/users1.txt    2    user2
hdfs://localhost.localdomain:8020/user/hive/warehouse/users/users2.txt    42    john.doe
```

If necessary, use the provided [string functions](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-StringFunctions) to trim the host and directories from the uri.

You can find the documentation on virtual columns here: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+VirtualColumns

Comment: Thanks a lot!. It is very helpful! Especially, if we search something out of huge number of log files created as external hive table, we will get to know the matching file names to get further insights.

Comment: @jkovacs is there an equivalent of INPUT__FILE__NAME in Presto?

Answer (score 8):

Every table in Hive has two virtual columns. They are

1. `INPUT__FILE__NAME`
2. `BLOCK__OFFSET__INSIDE__FILE`

`INPUT__FILE__NAME` gives the name of the file.
`BLOCK__OFFSET__INSIDE__FILE` is the current global file position.
Suppose if we want to find the name of the file corresponding to each record in a file. We can use the `INPUT__FILE__NAME` column. This feature is available from Hive versions above 0.8. A small example is given below.

Query

```
select INPUT__FILE__NAME, name from customer_data;
```

This will give us the file name corresponding to each record. If you want to get the file names corresponding to a hive table, the below query will help you.

```
select distinct(INPUT__FILE__NAME) from customer_data;
```

Answer (score 4):

Hive 0.8.0 provides support for two virtual columns:

One is `INPUT__FILE__NAME`, which is the input file's name for a mapper task.

the other is `BLOCK__OFFSET__INSIDE__FILE`, which is the current global file position.

For block compressed file, it is the current block's file offset, which is the current block's first byte's file offset.

Since Hive 0.8.0 the following virtual columns have been added:

> - ROW__OFFSET__INSIDE__BLOCK
> - RAW__DATA__SIZE
> - ROW__ID
> - GROUPING__ID

Updated link on virtual columns in hive:  https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+VirtualColumns