# Using awk to include file name with format in column

Tags: linux, unix, awk, hive

I'm working on wrangling some data to ingest into Hive. The problem is, I have overwrites in my historical data so I need to include the file name in the text files so that I can dispose of the duplicated rows which have been updated in subsequent files.

The way I've chosen to go about this is to use `awk` to add the file name to each file, then after I ingest into Hive I can use HQL to filter out my deprecated rows.

Here is my sample data (tab-delimited):

```
animal  legs    eyes
hippo   4       2
spider  8       8
crab    8       2
mite    6       0
bird    2       2
```

I've named it `long_name_20180901.txt`

I've figured out how to add my new column from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39048757/how-to-include-filename-in-first-column-of-existing-csv-file):

```
awk '{print FILENAME (NF?"\t":"") $0}' long_name_20180901.txt
```

which results in:

```
long_name_20180901.txt  animal  legs    eyes
long_name_20180901.txt  hippo   4       2
long_name_20180901.txt  spider  8       8
long_name_20180901.txt  crab    8       2
long_name_20180901.txt  mite    6       0
long_name_20180901.txt  bird    2       2
```

But, being a beginner, I don't know how to augment this command to:

1. make the column name (first line) something like "file_name"
2. implement regex in awk to just extract the part of the file name that I need, and dispose of the rest. I really just want `"long_name_(.{8,}).txt"` (the stuff in the capturing group.

Target output is:

```
file  animal  legs    eyes
20180901  spider  8       8
20180901  crab    8       2
20180901  mite    6       0
20180901  bird    2       2
```

Thanks for your time!! I'm a total newbie to `awk`.

Comment: What about simply using a HQL function instead?? cf. https://stackoverflow.com/a/16719530/5162372

Comment: thanks for the creative thinking here. I'll probably go this route since all my files are compressed and the decompress/recompress time needed to implement awk wont make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would handle one or multiple input files:

```
awk -v OFS='\t' '
    NR==1 { print "file", $0 }
    FNR==1 { n=split(FILENAME,t,/[_.]/); fname=t[n-1]; next }
    { print fname, $0 }
' *.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `BEGIN` that sets the "file" and then reset it to use the filename for the rest.

```
awk 'BEGIN{f="file\t"} NF{print f $0; if (f=="file\t") {l=split(FILENAME, a, /[_.]/); f=a[l-1]"\t"};}' long_name_20180901.txt
```